# Filter view based on several user profile fields (D7)

Tags: views, entities

I’m trying to apply automatically several filters to a view based on the corresponding profile fields selected by the current user.

For example, the users can select a favourite color (yellow, blue...) and a favourite food (fruit, meat...). If a user have selected that he likes "yellow" and "fruit", he should see in the view only the nodes that match both criteria (yellow fruits): bananas, lemons...

This is pretty easy to do when there's only 1 field to match (following the process indicated [here](http://drupal.org/node/1111722#comment-4315620)), but this same process doesn't seem to work for matching several fields (the content field of the view only allows 1 relationship).

I've tried creating relations between relationships (like "chain relationships") and doesn't seem to work, but maybe I'm doing something wrong (I don't have a really deep understanding of how relationships work).

Any ideas?
Maybe using the Relation or Entity Reference modules? Or some PHP code?

Comment: Somebody else can help me?

Comment: I've found two similar issues in drupal.org (http://drupal.org/node/562270 and http://drupal.org/node/557022) with PHP codes that should apply to my use case with slight changes, but my PHP knowledge is almost inexistent and I don't know what do I have to change exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many days of searching, testing and asking, I've finally found a solution here: http://blog.ampli.fi/filtering-a-drupal-7-view-based-on-multiple-user-profile-fields/#solution

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I had exactly the same problem and your answer has saved me many hours. My php skills are also not so great.

Comment: Please provide the solution here, not only a link. The link is dead by the way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should try chain relationship, this discussed [here](http://drupal.org/node/672002), similar problem to yours.
[Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/8645/how-do-i-set-up-a-drupal-view-with-two-relationships) the answer on similar question on drupal.stackexchange.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware of that thread (actually, I got the idea of using "chain relationships" from that particular answer of Merlinofchaos) but the problem discussed in that issue is quite different to mine and I don't know what do I have to change in order to make it work for my particular use case.